# Beautifulsoup scrape data-slug

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'd like to get data-slug value from page content such as below:

```
...
<div class="my_class" data-slug="I_want_to_scrap_it" data-title="Title">
<br> Some text </div>
...
```

I found it by find_all(class_="my_class") method, but I don't know how to extract "I_want_to_scrap_it" from it. Of course, I can convert it into string and get substring, but maybe there is a pretty simple Beautifulsoup method to do that.

Thank you and have a good day!

Comment: It's *scrape* **not** *scrap*...

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now it's scrape.

Comment: @MartinDomino Wouldn't hurt to show us your code. Would help us in getting the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
html = '''<div class="my_class" data-slug="I_want_to_scrap_it" data-title="Title">
<br> Some text </div>
'''

# solution using BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

div = soup.select('div.my_class')[0]
data_slug = div.get('data-slug')
print(data_slug)
```

`data-slug` is an attribute and can be retrieved using function `get()`.

Comment: Thank you Alexandra!